# Castle ActiveRecord using Linq to Nhibernate Example

Tags: castle-activerecord, linq-to-nhibernate

I have been using the ActiveRecord library for many years. Recently I started a new project and I'm including the AR 2.0 release in this project. I saw that it shipped with the Linq to Nhibernate library.  Are there any good examples of how to use Linq to Nhibernate with the Active Record library?

Answer (score 1):

Not the best examples I reckon, but you could take a look at [the tests](http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.ActiveRecord/tree/master/src/Castle.ActiveRecord.Linq.Tests/).

Answer (score 0):

LINQ-to-NHibernate is not very different while using in Castle Active Record. So refer to NHibernate's source on SourceForge and then find unit tests related to NHibernate-to-LINQ.